# vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow error in a terminal in VNC

Tags: opengl, ssh, x11, vtk, vnc

I run a vnc server on my workstation and connect with another computer. Both of the server and client are running Debian Jessie:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian-VAIO 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u2 (2016-06-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Xfce is installed for the vnc server and `xstartup` is:

```
$ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/sh
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
exec startxfce4
```

In the ~/.bashrc, I have added the lines below:

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=y
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6'
```

Currently, when I ssh to the server with `ssh -X`, the `$DISPLAY` is `localhost:10.0`, and the vtk related command will launch an X window. However, if a vnc server is launched in the ssh terminal, logging into xfce and opening a terminal in it, the `$DISPLAY` is `:1.0` and vtk fails to launch an X window, with the following message:

```
Error: In /home/orobix/Desktop/vmtk-build/VTK/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 394
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x2c30f10): Could not find a decent visual

Error: In /home/orobix/Desktop/vmtk-build/VTK/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 394
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x2c30f10): Could not find a decent visual

Error: In /home/orobix/Desktop/vmtk-build/VTK/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 394
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x2c30f10): Could not find a decent visual

Error: In /home/orobix/Desktop/vmtk-build/VTK/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 613
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x2c30f10): GLX not found.  Aborting.
```

I think it might be relate to the missed config of X server in `xstartup` of vnc server. But I don't know how to do it. Could anyone help me debug it? Any further information will be provided if needed. Thanks!

**20160823 Update**

I accepted the suggestion of VirtualGL + TurboVNC and installed the two components. A simple config using `vglserver_config` was done according to http://www.virtualgl.org/vgldoc/2_1_1/#hd009001 part 6.1. Then I made `vncserver` of TurboVNC to run xfce with `xstartup.turbovnc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
OS=`uname -s`
exec startxfce4
```

On the client, I use `vncviewer` of TurboVNC to connect the server. The desktop looks quite different from that in a default vncserver. Then I tried

```
/opt/VirtualGL/bin/vglrun vmtkimageviewer -ifile image_volume_voi.vti
```

in which the vmtkimageviewer should open up a window, but finally it gives out an error:

```
Executing vmtkimageviewer ...
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  17
  Current serial number in output stream:  16
```

And unfortunately, I find that with `ssh -X`, I cannot launch the X window as I did before, although `$DISPLAY` is still `localhost:10.0`. The output is:

```
Executing vmtkimageviewer ...
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38
```

But I think I am closer to the fact, as it looks like VirtualGL works(?). What to do for the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain and simple the X server variant that's being used by Xrdp (either Xvnc or Xvfb) simply doesn't support OpenGL / GLX and thus programs that need OpenGL will not work in that configuration.

Fallback to Mesa swrast or llvmpipe is possible though: http://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html

Comment: Does it mean that I shouldn't work in this way? I am just using a toolkit and it's hard for me to recompile it.

Comment: @purplezzh: Well you have two options: 1) Replace your `libGL.so` with one that will do without GLX extension on the server side and render using a software rasterizer. 2) Use a remote display system that fully supports OpenGL. OpenGL/GLX itself is network transparent; that's why `ssh -X` does work – the OpenGL commands are simply sent over the network and the X server / OpenGL driver on the terminal you're working on are doing the heavy lifting. However it's not very bandwidth efficient and using something like VirtualGL may be better suited. http://www.virtualgl.org/About/Introduction

Comment: @purplezzh: Also what works really well is using *Xpra*, configuring it to use a real GPU installed in the system for doing the rendering. You can even combine Xpra with Xrdp. The drawback is, that given the Xorg driver model only one X server at a time can access the GPU.

Comment: @purplezzh: Last but not least, over the past months a few software technologies appeared that allow off-screen OpenGL rendering without the need for a display server. Technically this would allow the VTK developers to decouple OpenGL from the display server. It's not there yet, but will likely appear, because you get it almost for free when supporting Wayland.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation! I have moved to VirtualGL + TurboVNC but met some obstacles. Could you help me further via the information I updated?

Comment: @purplezzh: The idea behind VirtualGL is, that there is an auxiliary X server running that's configured to use a GPU. All OpenGL rendering is redirected to that auxiliary X server and hence GPU and the resulting images then read back to the program running on the remote session. The errors you're getting there indicate that the auxiliary X server is not configured and/or running.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got everything done. [VirtualGL](http://virtualgl.org/) only is enough for my purpose. Just install and config as the section 6.2 & 6.3 in its [user's guide](http://www.virtualgl.org/vgldoc/2_1_1/#hd006002). Use the default `vncserver` and `vncviewer` as usual, TurboVNC is not needed. Use `vglrun` when you need an OpenGL support. One modification is that I should remove `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=y` in my `.bashrc`.

It runs fluent in my case. @datenwolf: Thank you again!